# assignment operator overloading problem

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, operator-keyword

This issue has me confused.  The first piece of code works fine without crashing, it assigns s1 to s2 perfectly fine.  But the second group of code causes the program to crash.

Anyone have any idea on why this is happening or what the problem could be?

Code 1:(works)

```
    s1.add(10, 30, 25, "Test Screen", false);
s1.add(13, 10, 5, "Name:XXX", false);
s1.add(13, 18, 30);
s1.remove(-1);
Screen s2 = s1;
```

Code 2:(crashes on assignment)

```
    Screen s1;

    if (1 != s1.add(10, 30, 25, "Test Screen", false))
        message("first add() has a problem");
   else if (2 != s1.add(13, 10, 5, "Name:XXX", false))
        message("second add() has a problem");
    else if (3 != s1.add(13, 18, 30))
        message("third add() has a problem");
    else if (3 != s1.remove(-1))
       message("first remove() has a problem");
    else {
        Screen s2 = s1;
}
```

Assignment operator for screen class:

```
        Screen& operator=(const Screen &scr) {
        if (this != &scr){
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                if  (fields[i])
                    delete fields[i];
                fields[i] = new LField();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < scr.numOfFields; i++)
                fields[i] = scr.fields[i];

            numOfFields = scr.numOfFields;
            currentField = scr.currentField;
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Assignment operator for Field class:

```
LField& operator=(const LField &lfieldobj) {
        if (this != &lfieldobj) {

            if (lfieldobj.val) {
                if (val)
                    delete[] val;
                val = new char[strlen(lfieldobj.val) + 1];
                strcpy(val, lfieldobj.val);
            }
            else{
                //val = new char[1];
                val = "";
            }
            rowNum = lfieldobj.rowNum;
            colNum = lfieldobj.colNum;
            width = lfieldobj.width;
            canEdit = lfieldobj.canEdit;
            index = lfieldobj.index;

        }
        return *this;
    }
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Without seeing the assignment operator definition, this is likely impossible to answer.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes on the assignment? `s2` will go out of scope as soon as it's created, so maybe it's a problem with the destructor?

Comment: I added the assignment operator defenitions.

I'm positive chris, in the code that crashes, I've commented out the assignment and it works fine.

Comment: Try the assignment without the destructor. Screen &s2(*(new Screen)); s2 = s1; perhaps

Comment: If your copy constructor is good then use the copy and swap idum for assignment operator. The current method you are using does not provide exception safety (you are currently provding no gurantees on the object if the assignment goes wrong).

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of your current `val` and replace it with an `std::string`. Get rid of your `fields` and replace it with an `std::vector`. That should let you eliminate *both* of your overloaded assignment operators; the compiler will provide ones that work. I'd guess you'll eliminate the memory management problems along with the code.

As it stands right now, even if you "fix" the memory management problem(s) you know about, you're going to be left with the fact that your code is completely unsafe in the face of exceptions (and uses `new` so it basically can't avoid exceptions either).

Answer (score 2):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < scr.numOfFields; i++)
            fields[i] = scr.fields[i];
```

That's not okay, you are copying a pointer instead of the pointed-to value.  A deep copy is required.

Answer (score 1):

What's the member "field" declaration?

`LField* fields[50]`?

If so, who's initializing the left hand side object fields member to `NULL`? I'd say that nobody... assignment operator is like copy constructor in C++, and you're invoking delete on a invalid pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Screen s2 = s1;
```

actually invokes the `Screen` copy constructor, not the assignment operator overload.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Screen
{
public:
        Screen() { }

        Screen(const Screen& s)
        {
                cout << "in `Screen::Screen(const Screen&)`" << endl;
        }

        Screen& operator=(const Screen& s)
        {
                cout << "in `Screen::operator=(const Screen&)`" << endl;
                return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
        Screen s1;
        Screen s2 = s1;
}
```

prints:

> in `Screen::Screen(const Screen&)`

I'm guessing that your `Screen` copy constructor is defined similar to `Screen::operator=(const Screen&)`, so a fix for the assignment operator overload may need to be applied to the copy constructor definition as well.

Also, how is the `fields` member of `Screen` defined? If it is like:

```
LField* fields[50];
```

then inside the constructors, you have to initialize all `LField*` objects in the array to `NULL` as they have undefined initial values:

```
std::fill_n(fields, 50, static_cast<LField*>(NULL));
```

Without this initialization, the test `if  (fields[i])` could succeed for some `i` even though `fields[i]` does not point to an allocation, causing your program to attempt to `delete` pointer(s) that were not returned by `new`.

Answer (score 0):

I've manged to fix it.  It was a problem with memory allocation after all :)

Comment: That may be but your code is **not** calling the assignment operator at all. The bug is in your copy constructor – you need to correct that as well.

Comment: and get rid of every new and delete, as Jerry suggested

Answer (score 0):

For complicated objects it is better to use the copy and swap idum.
This gives you an assignment operator with the strong exception gurantee (transactionaly safe). But it also means that you only have to consider the complicated creation of the object in one place (the constructors).

```
Screen& Screen::operator=(Screen const& rhs)
{
    Screen tmp(rhs);
    this->swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}

void Screen::swap(Screen const& rhs) throw ()
{
     // Swap each of the members for this with rhs.
     // Use the same pattern for Field.
}
```